# Assembly missing when using BackgroundAgent

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

When I try to use a BackgroundAgent I get the following error message when I open up the Background Applications screen at the System Settings.

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException was unhandled   Message=File or
>   assembly name
>   '\Applications\Install\EC78F0AC-625D-482E-9ADD-D48D58BE633A\Install\MyAgent.dll',
>   or one of its dependencies, was not found.   StackTrace:
>          at System.ThrowHelper.throwVersion37CompatException(ExceptionType
>   newEType, String newString, ExceptionType oldEType, String oldString)
>          at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String assemblyFile)
>          at Microsoft.Phone.BackgroundAgentActivator.LoadEntryPointAssembly(String
>   assemblyName)
>          at Microsoft.Phone.BackgroundAgentActivator.LoadAgent(String assemblyName, String typeName)
>          at Microsoft.Phone.BackgroundAgentActivator.Microsoft.Phone.IBackgroundAgentActivator.CreateBackgroundAgent(String
>   assembly, String typeinfo)
>          at Microsoft.Phone.BackgroundAgentDispatcher.AgentRequest.Invoke()
>          at Microsoft.Phone.BackgroundAgentDispatcher.InvocationThread()
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStartHelper(ThreadHelper t)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStartHelper()

I used this tutorial: http://rodrigueh.com/wp7-live-tiles-with-background-agents.

The sample provided works, but when I try to implement it it doesn't.. Unfortunetly I'm not able to find anything online.

Any ideas what is going on?

Kind regards,
Niels

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By looking at the exception the problem might be that you are not referencing MyAgent.dll in you main project. Add the background task as a reference and make sure this is added to your WMAppManifest.xml (replace it with actual assembly name and name of the task class.)

```
  <ExtendedTask Name="BackgroundTask">
    <BackgroundServiceAgent Specifier="ScheduledTaskAgent" Name="MyAgent" Source="MyAgent" Type="MyAgent.ScheduledAgent" />
  </ExtendedTask>
```